# MySQL - Why query does not sum same type of data if I use more left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

My schema and sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE `bsbi_hedge_fund` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `fund_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `abn_number` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_no` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_one` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_two` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_tbl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'active',
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bsbi_hedge_fund`
--

INSERT INTO `bsbi_hedge_fund` (`id`, `fund_name`, `abn_number`, `parent_company_id`, `email`, `contact_no`, `address_one`, `address_two`, `city_name`, `state_name`, `zip_code`, `country_tbl_id`, `status`, `created_by`, `created_date`, `modified_by`, `modified_date`) VALUES
(1, 'iCAP Hedge Funds', '53616271062', 1, 'icaptrading@gmail.com', '0425175887', '68 Roy Marika Street', '', 'Bonner', 'ACT', '2914', 12, 'active', 1, '2020-02-20 07:02:51', NULL, NULL);


CREATE TABLE `bsbi_company` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `company_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `abn_number` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `acn_number` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_no` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_one` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_two` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_tbl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'active',
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `allocated_money` float(17,5) DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `hedge_fund_allocation` float(17,5) NOT NULL,
  `investment_class_allocation` float(17,5) NOT NULL,
  `hedge_fund_money` float(10,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `inv_class_money` float(10,3) DEFAULT '0.000'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bsbi_company`
--

INSERT INTO `bsbi_company` (`id`, `company_name`, `abn_number`, `acn_number`, `email`, `contact_no`, `address_one`, `address_two`, `city_name`, `state_name`, `zip_code`, `country_tbl_id`, `status`, `created_by`, `created_date`, `modified_by`, `modified_date`, `allocated_money`, `hedge_fund_allocation`, `investment_class_allocation`, `hedge_fund_money`, `inv_class_money`) VALUES
(1, 'Investment and Capital Growth for Australian Professional ( ', '53616271062', '2123', 'abc@gmail.com', '2343', '68 Roy Marika Street', '', 'Bonner', 'ACT', '2914', 12, 'active', 1, '2020-02-20 07:01:26', 1, '2020-03-07 12:13:53', 22847.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 20000.000, 19000.000);


CREATE TABLE `bsbi_hedge_fund_journal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hedge_fund_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` float(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tran_type` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bsbi_hedge_fund_journal`
--

INSERT INTO `bsbi_hedge_fund_journal` (`id`, `company_id`, `hedge_fund_id`, `amount`, `tran_type`, `created_by`, `created_date`, `modified_by`, `modified_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 20000.000, 'credit', 1, '2020-03-07 11:45:40', NULL, NULL);

CREATE TABLE `bsbi_investment_allocation_class_journal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hedge_fund_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `investment_class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` float(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tran_type` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bsbi_investment_allocation_class_journal`
--

INSERT INTO `bsbi_investment_allocation_class_journal` (`id`, `hedge_fund_id`, `investment_class_id`, `amount`, `tran_type`, `created_by`, `created_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 18000.000, 'credit', 1, '2020-03-07 11:46:09'),
(2, 1, 1, 2000.000, 'credit', 1, '2020-03-07 12:12:02'),
(3, 1, 1, 1000.000, 'debit', 1, '2020-03-07 12:13:53');
```

...and fiddle of same ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cd46d/2 ):

I have written the following query to fetch some data from the database:

```
SELECT
hf.*, com.company_name company_name, com.id com_id,
IFNULL( SUM( hfc.amount ), 0 ) hedge_credit, IFNULL( SUM( hfd.amount ), 0 ) hedge_debit,
IFNULL( SUM( cjc.amount ), 0 ) class_credit, IFNULL( SUM( cjd.amount ), 0 ) class_debit

FROM bsbi_hedge_fund hf

INNER JOIN bsbi_company com ON hf.parent_company_id = com.id

LEFT JOIN bsbi_hedge_fund_journal hfc ON (hfc.hedge_fund_id = hf.id AND hfc.tran_type='credit')
LEFT JOIN bsbi_hedge_fund_journal hfd ON ( hfd.hedge_fund_id = hf.id AND hfd.tran_type = 'debit' )
LEFT JOIN bsbi_investment_allocation_class_journal cjc ON (cjc.hedge_fund_id = hf.id AND cjc.tran_type = 'credit' )
LEFT JOIN bsbi_investment_allocation_class_journal cjd ON (cjd.hedge_fund_id = hf.id AND cjd.tran_type = 'debit' )
ORDER BY hf.id ASC
```

Here is the output of this query:
[image: result of query 1]

The problem I face is: **hedge_credit** value is **20000** but it shows **40000**! similarly **class_debit** is **1000** but it shows **2000**

After doing some R&D what I found is: **bsbi_investment_allocation_class_journal** table has two entry having **tran_type = credit** but for some unknown reason the following line of my query fetch two rows, rather *sum the values* (and I fear the same thing will happen to other left join if they also have more than one record of the same type!)

```
LEFT JOIN bsbi_investment_allocation_class_journal cjc ON (cjc.hedge_fund_id = hf.id AND cjc.tran_type = 'credit' )
```

If I add **Group By clause** to above query then I got:
[image]

Notice that **class_credit** has two different values that should sum up but does not sum for an unknown reason!!

Can anyone tell me what is actually wrong in my query that raises this issue?
- Thanks

Comment: @Strawberry: Check this if you want to reproduce the problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cd46d/2

Comment: Table 'db_9_9cd46d.bsbi_country' doesn't exist

Comment: I don't know how this query is able to run.

Comment: @Strawberry Why do you copy this query rather than run the one available on sqlfiddle? I have removed all queries related to the country table.

UPD: I update the query here also.

Comment: @Strawberry, by the way, bro I got the solution using this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154586/sum-over-distinct-rows-with-multiple-joins

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Joins generate all possible combinations of rows that meet join criteria. Because you're using only `hfc.hedge_fund_id = hf.id` to join tables, you are duplicating rows. If there were three transactions in total, each would be tripled..

You'll need to select more data from the tables containing transactions to keep the rows unique: timestamps or transaction ids. I would usually select the unique rows that I want first, then left join the non-unique data (name,  country, etc) to each row.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154586/sum-over-distinct-rows-with-multiple-joins

If someone faces the exact type of problem then they can check this solution: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154586/sum-over-distinct-rows-with-multiple-joins